# Material Design and Ionicons in select option in React

Tags: reactjs, html-select, ionicons, material-design-icons, react-icons

How can I add icons in select dropdown?

My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Icon from '@mdi/react'
import { mdiFormatAlignLeft } from '@mdi/js';
import { mdiCheckboxMarked } from '@mdi/js';
import { IoMdRadioButtonOn } from 'react-icons/io';

class AddNewQuestion extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <select>
            <option value='multiple'><Icon path={mdiCheckboxMarked} /> Multiple choice</option>
            <option value='single'><IoMdRadioButtonOn /> Single choice</option>
            <option value='open'><Icon path={mdiFormatAlignLeft} /> Open question</option>
          </select>
        </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Instead of the icon, I get [object Object].
[image: screenshot]

I tried to put MD icon as a webfont, as described here: https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/webfont but I also get [object Object].

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<select>` and `<option>` are native UI elements, so you're constrained to how the users's operating system renders them. `<option>` elements can only contain text strings, not HTML or React nodes.

What you're looking for is something like the [Material UI Select Component](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/), which creates its own DOM elements to simluate the experience of using a `<select>`, giving you the ability to style it, add icon elements to dropdown options, etc.